# Rotate Zooming ImageView in ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` that has a zooming `UIImageView`, ie it implements:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

I'm trying to add a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to this `imageView` and I do it as follows:

```
_rotationGestureRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:_rotationGestureRecognizer];

-(void)rotate:(id)sender
{
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGestureRecognizer = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender retain];

    if(rotationGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        self.lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (self.lastRotation - rotationGestureRecognizer.rotation);
    rotationGestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationGestureRecognizer.view.transform, rotation);
    self.lastRotation = rotationGestureRecognizer.rotation;

    [rotationGestureRecognizer release];
}
```

I'm just wondering, is it possible to even do this? It seems the `UIScrollView` is blocking the touches to my `UIImageView` because nothing is happening. Does Apple recommend to not do this with a zooming view in a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: use KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer for rotation

Comment: @CoDEFRo If you want to rotate scrollView then use adding gesture to scrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is working.Add gesture to scrollView instead of imageView.

```
 UIRotationGestureRecognizer* _rotationGestureRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
 [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:_rotationGestureRecognizer];
```

**Swift 5 Version:**

```
let rotationGestureRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.rotate(_:)))
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: This is a good fix, however I found it tough to incorporate rotation with the UIScrollView imageView because the scale transformation seems to reset the entire transformation. Nothing to do with the answer which is the best possible way to do it, but I think maybe best to create your own zooming imageView if you want to do rotation.

Comment: You're a savior man! I was trying to figure this out form hours :)

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender
{   
    [self bringSubviewToFront:[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view]]; 
    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {       
        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);  
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);   
    [[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];    
    lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
    lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}
```